# Vagrant status – where to see running box version?

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

How I can view which box version is running with 'vagrant status'? Yes I know there is no documented parameters for the command, so how can this be found out? Am using VirtualBox 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'vagrant status' doesn't show the box version.

'vagrant box outdated' would show the current version, but only if you're not running the latest one.

If 'vagrant box outdated' doesn't output anything, that would mean your box is up to date, and a lookup at atlas.hashicorp.com is required to figure out the current version.